# VB.NET 2019 How to populate a Tag Property on a dynamic ToolstripmenuItem

Tags: vb.net, tags

I am struggling to populate a tag property on a dynamically created sub menu which I have created. I have a text file that contains a number of radio station names, BBC1, BBC2, BBC3 for example, as well as the associated stream addresses for said stations. I am able to pull in the names and apply it to the submenu. They appear fine. I can click on the submenus, and the sender() variable confirms the station names correctly. My problem is that I cannot get the Tag property for each sub menu/radio station, to store the stream address. The code gets the radio title cleans the code and inserts it into the RadioStreamsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(station_name) and all is fine. The code then gets the Stream address and inserts it here RadioStreamsToolStripMenuItem.Tag.ToString(). I can tell that it is wrong, but how do I go about ensuring the correct stream goes into the correct radio Tag property. Im very new to this so please be gentle, its just a little hobby.

```
'======================================================================  
'Aquires Radio name and creates a dropdown sub menu within RadioStreams  
'======================================================================   

Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
    If line.StartsWith("#") Then
        station_name = Replace(line, "#", "")
        Dim x = RadioStreamsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(station_name)
        AddHandler x.Click, AddressOf ToolMenuItem_Click
        '===================================================
        'Aquires Radio Stream to add to the Tag property for each new station                                   
        '===================================================
    ElseIf line.StartsWith("@") Then
        Dim station_stream As String = Replace(line, "@", "")
        'The following just checks if the data has gone into the correct place
        For Each Myitem As ToolStripItem In RadioStreamsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
            If Myitem.Text = station_name Then
                MsgBox("MyItems  " & Myitem.ToString())
                Me.Tag = station_stream
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: You're accessing the `Click` event here: `AddHandler x.Click, AddressOf ToolMenuItem_Click`. Why would access the `Tag` property be any different?

Comment: Forgive me but I really dont know, but are you saying that I could do ToolMenuItem_Tag? Does the Tag Item exist when I create a new submenu or should I be creating it? Sorry to sound so dumb.

Comment: Why are you setting `Me.Tag = station_stream`? Do you know what is `Me` here (not the ToolStripMenuItem). You don't need those `If ElseIf`, create a class object that contains both strings, already *cleaned*, as property values and use them to set the Item text and Tag. You may find out that you don't even need the Tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary to store the stations a stream addresses. Dictionary lookups are very fast.

I assumed from your code that your text file looks like this

#BBC1
@BBC1streamAddress
#BBC2
@BBC2streamAddress
#BBC3
@BBC3streamAddress

I looped through the lines of the file assigning the trimmed keys and values to the dictionary. Then looped through the dictionary filling the menu. When the user clicks a menu item we get the text of the item and search the dictionary for the correct stream address.

```
Private RadioDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Radio.txt")

    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1 Step 2
        RadioDictionary.Add(lines(i).Trim("#"c), lines(i + 1).Trim("@"c))
    Next
    For Each item In RadioDictionary
        Dim x = RadioStreamsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item.Key)
        AddHandler x.Click, AddressOf ToolMenuItem_Click
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ToolMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolMenuItem.Click
    Dim station = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripDropDownItem).Text
    Dim stream = RadioDictionary(station)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your comments. I had a go with your code Mary and unfortunately I get the following error... based on this code for some reason. RadioDictionary.Add(lines(i).Trim("#"c), lines(i + 1).Trim("@"c))  System.IndexOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=Mini_Media_Streamer

Comment: Oops! Very sorry! `For i = 0 To lines.Length Step 2` should be `For i = 0 To lines.Length -1 Step 2`